# NStimer loads repeated value

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I am using an `NSTimer` running every second to load a string in a label that the user sees from `NSUserdefults`. When the user picks from a `UITableView` a string, this string is saved in the `userdefaults`, and the timer running every second updates the label with the user's choice. is there a way to ckeck if a value in the `NSUserdefults` has changed without using a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the app's user defaults are modified by another app (an unlikely occurrence, and I'm not even sure if that's possible on iOS), your app should *know* when the value changes. If it happens in a background thread, you can use [`NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) to alert other components of your app that the value has changed.